# Git Push "everything up to date" but file on github not change

Tags: github

after i learn to commit a file to github. now i have try to update file on github
by run syntax

```
git push -u origin main
```

and output message

```
Everything up-to-date
Branch 'main' set up to track remote branch 'main' from 'origin'.
```

when i check again on github the file that i was push no change at all
[image]

here my local file

[image]

please help me, im new to github

Comment: What's your `git status` in the local repo?

Comment: (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   index.html
        renamed:    lib/reactjs/babel.js -> lib/babel.js
        renamed:    lib/reactjs/react-dom.production.min.js -> lib/react-dom.production.min.js
        renamed:    lib/reactjs/react.production.min.js -> lib/react.production.min.js
        new file:   src/js/App.js

Comment: [Edit] the question. And a [link to the repo](https://github.com/dwirput/ReactJs) is more use than a screenshot. But it seems like you have some things pushed to GitHub and some changes in your local state, it's unclear what was unexpected here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you committed first? With git, you need to commit your changes first, which is like saving each version locally. Then, when you push, you are publishing all of your versions to the remote (github).

Try the following:

```
git status
```

if it tells you about untracked files, use:

```
git add <filepath>
```

then:

```
git commit -m "<some commit message>"
```

This will save your changes as a commit locally, and you can now push this commit to github with the push command you used earlier.

Comment: thanks it works for me